# Reusing a Custom View

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am working on a chatting app. I created a custom compound view (LinearLayout) at the bottom of the chatting screen to send emojis, pics and videosjust like below image of facebook messenger.

[image]

The problem is whenever I come to chatting screen I have to do the following for this compound view:

1. Find all the views by Id.
2. Fetch all images from phone gallery.
3. Show these images in the ImageViews.
4. Initialize many other variables.

Performing all these steps takes like 1-2 seconds and as a result of which my screen is delayed.

Is it possible to perform all the above 4 steps at one place and just use this view wherever I want? I want to initialize this view just once and use it in all the chatting screen or any other screen/activites without initializing again?

Comment: Use fragments: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @Jones Even fragments need to be initialized. All the views inside fragment need to be initialized.

Comment: How about loading your images and other strenuous tasks asynchronously and on demand, that way you will have no interruptions on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try make something like Sliding menu. This linearLayout place in MainActivity, Chat & etc place in fragments and then use FragmentManager to change Fragments.

Comment: I think this should be a comment.